# Visual Basic - Add an entry to a list in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 2 sheets. Sheet1 is named Form and Sheet2 is named Data. I am trying to have a form on Sheet1 that creates a new row in Sheet2. I am pretty new to VBA and am really just trying to teach myself through Google. My question is, how can you reference a sheet that isnt active and have it codify the information as intended without visually switching tabs?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Very Respectfully,

Adam Walker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Sub add_row()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    ws2.Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

The above will add a new row at the top of sheet 2.
If you have more than 1 action to perform on a different sheet, you can also use a with statement.

```
Option Explicit
Sub add_data()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    With ws2
        .Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlDown
        .Cells(1, 1).Value2 = "Rows shifted down by 1!"
    End With
End Sub
```

I hope this is of help for you.

Comment: Placing this information here, while it answered this question, also answered a couple of other questions I had. I appreciate you posting this, even though it appears to be a bit overkill for this question. Thank you for taking your time to write this out.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the macro recorder will teach you how to do things. However, it does write very obtuse code and always works with `Active*` (Cell, Range, WorkSheet, etc) by using `.select`, which you've figured out, isn't very efficient or pretty.

Try this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.worksheets("Form").range("A1") = "This goes on the Form sheet"
ActiveWorkbook.worksheet("Data").range("A1") = "This goes on the Data sheet"
```

Of course, that relies on `ActiveWorkbook`, but you get the idea.

Comment: It is always good to know another way to do things as well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all since you're new to vba you learn to declare in the right way so all people can understand what you are saying, when you say form it get to vague, is it a userform or a formula can you understand?

About the reference to another sheet that is not active just declare like this:

```
Workbooks("example.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
```

this declaration will insert a new row on the row 1, with that example you can get how to declare wich workbook, worksheet and range you want to work on

Comment: This gives me what I was looking for. I also appreciate the feedback. I was really struggling to come up with what i had there. Knowing that "form" is ambiguous will help me in trying to explain questions in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Overkill example**: here's the `Form` sheet with a sample form. The `Submit` button has been assigned the macro `SubmitForm`, which is a procedure created in VBA (code to follow).

Named Ranges can be very useful in VBA when looking to retrieve values from a specific cell or cells. By assigning NamedRanges to each field of the form, we can retrieve their values in VBA simply by using `Range("NamedRangeName").Value`

- The `First` field has been assigned the NamedRange `FormFirstName`
- The `Last` field has been assigned the NamedRange `FormLastName`
- The `Email` field has been assigned the NamedRange `FormEmail`

[image: Form]

Below is what the `Data` sheet in my example looks like. We have a header row, then blank rows underneath it. As the `Submit` button on the `Form` sheet is clicked, a new record (row) will be created here.

**Data Sheet Before Submit Clicked**

[image: Data Sheet Before]

**Data Sheet After Submit Clicked**

[image: Data Sheet After]

And here's the `SubmitForm` procedure code that goes along with this sample. It does the following when a user submits the form by clicking the button:

- Retrieve values from the `Form` sheet fields via the assigned `NamedRanges`
- Find the next empty row on the `Data` sheet
- Insert the retrieved values from the form

```
Public Sub SubmitForm()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual

Dim userFirstName As String
Dim userLastName As String
Dim userEmail As String

'   get a reference to the Form worksheet
Dim formWorksheet As Worksheet
Set formWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form")

'   using the named ranges, retrieve the form field values
userFirstName = formWorksheet.Range("FormFirstName").Value
userLastName = formWorksheet.Range("FormLastName").Value
userEmail = formWorksheet.Range("FormEmail").Value

Dim dataWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim headerRow As Integer
Dim nextUserRow As Integer
Dim userIdColumn As Integer
Dim firstNameColumn As Integer
Dim lastNameColumn As Integer
Dim emailColumn As Integer
Dim createdDateColumn As Integer

'   get a reference to the Data worksheet
Set dataWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
headerRow = 1

'   get the number of used rows (rows that contain data) on this worksheet,
'   then add one to it. This will be the next empty row where our new
'   record will live
nextUserRow = dataWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

'   set the columns for each field
userIdColumn = 1
firstNameColumn = 2
lastNameColumn = 3
emailColumn = 4
createdDateColumn = 5

'   persist the data retrieved from the Form sheet to the Data sheet row
dataWorksheet.Cells(nextUserRow, userIdColumn).Value = (nextUserRow - headerRow)
dataWorksheet.Cells(nextUserRow, firstNameColumn).Value = userFirstName
dataWorksheet.Cells(nextUserRow, lastNameColumn).Value = userLastName
dataWorksheet.Cells(nextUserRow, emailColumn).Value = userEmail
dataWorksheet.Cells(nextUserRow, createdDateColumn).Value = Now

Application.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```